# Storing a value in a matrix using a loop

Tags: r, matrix

My code is:

```
set.seed(100)
n <- 10
d <- rep(NA, n)
d[1] <- 0
y <- runif(n)
a <- 10

for (i in 2:length(y)) {
    d[i] <- d[i-1] + y[i-1]
} #This creates an interval with endpoints at my y uniform RVs

store.x <- NULL
for (j in 1:a) {
    x <- runif(1, min =0, max =sum(y))
    for (i in 1:length(y)) {
        if (x <= d[i+1] && x > d[i]) {
            store.x[j] <- i
            break
        }
    }
}  #This tells you which interval my x uniform RV is in
```

Now instead of store.x being a vector that tells me what intervals x falls into, I want it to be stored in the corresponding row and column of a matrix with the value of 1.  So for my first x since it falls into interval 7, my matrix will be all zeros except for a one in the first row, seventh column and a one in the seventh row, first column.

Any ideas on how to do this would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Why should be "all zeros except for a one in the first row, seventh column and a one in the seventh row, first column"? Is not "all zeros except for a one in the first row, seventh column" already enough?

Comment: @adiana Just so it is symmetric

Comment: So a should be always the same as length(y)?

Comment: So how can the matrix be symmetric if the dimensions are a and length(y)?

Comment: The dimensions are n by n.  "a" is just the number of x uniform RVs that I have and n is the number of y uniform RVs.  So there could be a 10 X 10 matrix with any number of x RVs populating it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can more efficiently implement this algorithm using vectorized calls to [`runif()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Uniform.html), [`cumsum()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cumsum.html), and [`findInterval()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/findInterval.html):

```
set.seed(1L); ## seed the PRNG for reproducible results
n <- 10L; ## length of x, y, and result matrix dimensions
y <- runif(n); ## produce random interval lengths
yb <- cumsum(c(0,y)); ## calculate interval boundaries
x <- runif(n,0,yb[length(yb)]); ## generate random x values
i <- findInterval(x,yb); ## find which intervals contain the x values
m <- matrix(0,n,n); ## init the result matrix
m[matrix(c(seq_len(n),i,i,seq_len(n)),ncol=2L)] <- 1; ## symmetric 1 assignment
m; ## print result
##       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
##  [1,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
##  [2,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
##  [3,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
##  [4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1     0
##  [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
##  [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     0
##  [7,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
##  [8,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     1
##  [9,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
## [10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
```

Technically, the way you've written the interval test `x <= d[i+1] && x > d[i]` means that you want the left boundary to be *open* and the right boundary to be *closed* for each interval. It appears that `findInterval()` has only recently added support for this variation on its logic, specifically in the `r69814` development snapshot (which will eventually become `R-3.3.0`). So you probably don't have access to it yet, but when you do, you can pass `left.open=T` to get that behavior.

---

If we have `a` elements of `x` allowing for `a != n` then we have to decide how to map the index of each element in `x` to the index of the result matrix. The above solution assumes that `a == n` and that there is a direct mapping between the two index domains.

If we consider the elements of `x` to correspond to result matrix indexes `1:n` in a cyclic fashion, then we can define `xi` to be the cyclic index, taking `yi` as `i`, i.e. the `y` interval index in which the `x` element landed. We can then aggregate all `(xi,yi)` hits to produce a count for each cell.

If you still want symmetry, then we can further accumulate the count for each `(yi,xi)`, thus double-counting each hit, once for each of the two symmetric cells.

```
set.seed(1L); ## seed the PRNG for reproducible results
n <- 10L; ## length of y and result matrix dimensions
a <- 100L; ## length of x
y <- runif(n); ## produce random interval lengths
yb <- cumsum(c(0,y)); ## calculate interval boundaries
x <- runif(a,0,yb[length(yb)]); ## generate random x values
i <- findInterval(x,yb); ## find which intervals contain the x values
m <- matrix(0,n,n); ## init the result matrix
hit <- as.matrix(aggregate(n~xi+yi,cbind(xi=seq_len(n),yi=i,n=1),sum)); ## aggregate hits
m[hit[,c('xi','yi')]] <- m[hit[,c('xi','yi')]]+hit[,'n']; ## add n to xi,yi
m[hit[,c('yi','xi')]] <- m[hit[,c('yi','xi')]]+hit[,'n']; ## add n to yi,xi
m; ## print result
##       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
##  [1,]    0    0    1    2    0    3    3    1    2     0
##  [2,]    0    2    2    2    1    1    3    3    1     0
##  [3,]    1    2    0    4    1    5    4    2    0     1
##  [4,]    2    2    4   10    1    2    1    1    3     2
##  [5,]    0    1    1    1    0    3    2    6    0     2
##  [6,]    3    1    5    2    3    2    3    5    1     0
##  [7,]    3    3    4    1    2    3    4    2    3     3
##  [8,]    1    3    2    1    6    5    2    2    3     2
##  [9,]    2    1    0    3    0    1    3    3    2     2
## [10,]    0    0    1    2    2    0    3    2    2     0
```

Comment: This is great, thanks!  What if I wanted to add 1 to the assignment instead of just calling it 1?  So if I  have hundreds a's I can see how many are in the row/column

Answer (score 1):

```
store.x <- matrix(0,nrow=length(y),ncol=length(y))
for(j in 1:length(y)) {
x <- runif(1, min= 0, max =sum(y))
for(i in 1:length(y)) {
    if(x <= d[i+1] &&  x > d[i]) {
        store.x[j,i] <- 1
        store.x[i,j] <- 1
        break
    }}}
```